# Full Calendar responsive

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3, fullcalendar-2

I've been running with this problem when i view my calendar on 'Mobile' or even 'Ipad' the event slots are just not user friendly can't even see the events.However there's no issues with Height.Only  problem with Width. Can anyone help. Thanks in advance 
Here's the code:-

```
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        minTime: '#{@timing_slots[:start_time]}',
        maxTime: '#{@timing_slots[:end_time]}',
        slotDuration: '00:45:00',
        //themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
        aspectRatio: 2.8,
        contentHeight:'auto',
        slotEventOverlap: false,
        defaultDate: date,
        editable: false,
        selectable: true,
```

[Ipad view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFtIN.png)

Comment: Unfortunately fullCalendar uses a fixed grid system to render the calendar, and of course this is not very well suited to smalls screens. There's not much you can do about it. This kind of thing has been asked before if you search. I would suggest you could implement your page so that if the page is loaded (or resized) to a small screen it does something like re-draw the calendar so it only shows one day at a time - maybe a list or agenda view of a single day, something which is suited to a small amount of space. You have to write the code for that switch though

Comment: Yea with little study about fullCalendar found out it is not well suited to smaller screens. However i was trying to switch to agenda week or month for smaller screens that atleast  has pop up option where the user can go and view the number of events by clicking the "View more link". @ADyson

Comment: is there anyway you can change the default view of the full calendar according to the width size of the screen. I'm trying to implement that with this line code "defaultView: (function () { if ($(window).width() >= 768) { return defaultView = 'agendaDay'; } else { return defaultView = 'month'; } })(),". It's working fine however you have to refresh the browser everytime to view the changes. Anything without refereshing the page . I tried windowResize function but no Luck @ADyson. Any help would really be appreciated . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In regard to your question in the comments about changing the view; yes, you can do this using the **changeView** method. So, maybe try something like this:

```
if (window.innerWidth >= 768 ) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
} else {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month');
}
```

[changeView Docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/changeView)

Hope that helps.